# Is it possible for me to use a program on Windows 8 that is already installed on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, multi-boot

I have Windows 7/8 dual-booting, and want to install some programs on both operating systems. Is there any way I can achieve this without having to install it twice?

Comment: never tried win 8 so i'm not answering but if win 8 can see win 7 partition then yes you can

Comment: If the program writes information into the registry, no.

Answer (score 4):

Some programs can be used without installing to both operating systems by simply creating a shortcut that points to the .exe on the other OS's partition. For programs that use the registry or have special dependencies that will not work, you could go to: http://portableapps.com/ and try to find a modified version of the program you want that *will work* with the previously mentioned method.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether the program stores OS specific data within the files of the installation directory, you could actually install the software twice (once through each OS) and have both OS's pointing to that same installation directory:

Example: `C:\Program Files\ *NAMEOFAPP*`

NOTE: The 2nd time you perform the installation, the original files will be overwritten, but the 1st OS registry will remain intact, while another registry is created for the 2nd OS.

This will install 2 unique instances of registry keys into their respective OS registries, but only require the single installation directory.

It really depends on the software though, but worth a try because Win7/8 are pretty similar.